# ffmpeg: crop then scale does not work

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to crop black border, then scale to video to `1280x720`, however, the following command does not work，`crop` works well, but `scale` has no effect:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:v]crop=1424:720:0:40[c0];[c0]scale=1280:720[bg]' -map '[bg]' -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scale filter adjusts the aspect ratio, so that the display ratio remains the same. Assuming you don't want that.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf crop=1424:720:0:40,scale=1280:720,setsar=1 -c:a copy output.mp4
```